# How to get 100 record of each customer in a single query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a location table now I have to keep only 100 record for each customer and have to move rest of them to another server.

**using this query We can get customers list**

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_location_history WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE()) < 30) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(1) < 100
```

Now suppose we have a list of customer like

I am trying to write a single query to get all the record for each customer which is greater then 100.

- 125452
- 412555
- 554114
- 258471

Please suggest ....

Comment: Have you looked at partitioning?

Comment: How can we know which 100 of them you want? date column? id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: i want to keep latest 100 records of each user & move rest records into another server. It is basically based on the count of records.

Comment: Use ORDER BY DESC functionality in mysql

Comment: @Gopal I have to keep latest 100 record of each user

Answer (score 0):

This will get the latest 100 records of each customer

```
SELECT   user_id, substring_index(group_concat(sample_id ORDER BY sample_id DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 100) limit100, FROM     user_location_history  GROUP BY user_id ;
```

Comment: Please find the table structure [Image](http://52.6.142.97/Latlong.png) and provide a details query ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it generates a row number for each record :-

```
set @num := 0, @group := '';
select *
from 
(
   select user_id,
      @num := if(@group = `user_id`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @group := `user_id` as dummy
  from user_location_history
  WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,FROM_UNIXTIME(location_date/1000),SYSDATE()) < 30)
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 100;
```